# async on page load in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin

I'm currently developping a small application based on a Master Detail template. One of my `Pages` requires some data to be loaded immediatly, and I dont know how to do this. In every example, data is loaded once user press a button.

Here is my current code :

```
string test = async (sender, e) => {

    Task<string> json = GetRandomRelations ();
    return await json;
};
```

And my method

```
public async Task<string> GetRandomRelations () {

        var client              = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient ();
        client.BaseAddress      = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/loltools/web/app_dev.php/api/relation/");
        string response         = await client.GetStringAsync("random/20");

        return response;
    }
```

I'm currently just trying to get the json response, but I cannot even manage to do that... My main problem is that I cannot convert the lambda expression to string...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

> One of my Pages requires some data to be loaded immediatly, and I dont know how to do this.

Think about this for a bit. What you're really asking is how to reconcile two opposing requirements:

1. The page must show some data immediately. The UI must be responsive. The data must be available synchronously to display.
2. The data is retrieved asynchronously. It is not available immediately. It will take some (unknown) amount of time to even *get* the data to display.

So, obviously, there's no direct solution. Instead, you have to satisfy the both of the core requirements ("The UI must be responsive" and "The data is retrieved asynchronously") in a different way. One common approach is to (immediately and synchronously) display a "Loading..." view of the data - a spinner or whatnot. Then, *update* the display when the data arrives.

Comment: Yeah I'm currently showing a loader in my page, but I dont know how to code it. Have you got any example ?

Comment: @solarBanana: I've never used Xamarin Forms, but I imagine `INotifyPropertyChanged` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure what you are trying to do but what's wrong with simply:

```
string test = await GetRandomRelations ();
```

Comment: in order to use `await`, it requires a `async` method. Does not seem to be a `async void PageFinishedRendering()` method that exists on pages by default.